# Question Simplifying Summation

Tags: probability

$$ \sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} p(i) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} \binom nip^i(1-p)^{n-i} = [\ p + (1-p)]^n = 1 $$

I don't understand how ni turns into p. If you multiply pi to (1-p)n-i it become (1-p)n but what happens to the ni and where does the p at the beginning come from.

Comment: The $(ni)$ is $\binom ni$ and the rest follows from the binomial theorem.

Comment: I don't understand. I'm reading the textbook but it's not making sense.

Comment: @Undergradstudent: Which equality don’t you understand: the first, or the second?

Comment: @Brian M. Scott
$$ \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} \binom nip^i(1-p)^{n-i} = [\ p + (1-p)]^n = 1 $$

I don't understand this step. How it simplifies from the summation of the $$ \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} \binom nip^i(1-p)^{n-i} $$ to
$$  [\ p + (1-p)]^n = 1 $$

Comment: As Ted said, it’s just the binomial theorem, $$(x+y)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}kx^ky^{n-k}\;,$$ with $x=p$ and $y=1-p$.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott. Ohhh. Okay now it makes sense. Thanks. So it just a property that I have to memorize?

Comment: Use the definition of the binomial theorem.

Comment: You should definitely learn the binomial theorem; it’s very useful and comes up quite often.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott I think I remember it now from pre-calc I think. I just haven't used it since then.